# Css are declared in Head section still found in body part by YSlow why?

Tags: html, css, yslow

I am using YSlow to measure overall page performance. However, CSS are declared in Head section of the document still YSlow finds css in the body of the document and suggests to put CSS at top. What may be the reason for the same?

I am not using CSS property in hard code or inline style, for inline style I am applying class to that div like `<div class="header"></div>`. Also in head tag there is external CSS attched like

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/menu.css" />
</head>
```

But YSlow finds css in body part rather than head section.

Comment: Are you setting particular css properties in hard code? for example <input style="....."></input)>? Or in your body you add specific CSS? Could you post the code? Difficult to answer.

Comment: I wonder if you're comparing the same page with YSlow. I mean is it possible you're viewing the code on a test server and YSlow is reporting on the live server (for example). Can you right click on the page YSlow is reporting this on and view the source to confirm the code is what you expect.

Comment: @Dave Rook i have live and test server too. However in test server it suggested to put script at bottom while in live no suggestion as such and what suggestion i find for css in live there is nothing as such for test server. So its all confusing as a whole.

Comment: But if YSlow is comparing the live site then it means it's comparing a different document

Comment: how's that possible? comparing different document.

Comment: To take a step back, since you are already including the CSS in the head, you could ignore (not worry about) the YSlow warning. Also if you have a public URL you could share, others could troubleshoot your observations further, if that's helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear, but I would guess you probably have in line CSS tags

Something like

```
 <div style="float:left">asf asdf</div>
```

So, your document could be

```
<html>
<head>
<!--CSS declarations and title etc-->
</head>
<body>
<!--body code etc referencing the exteranl CSS sheets or the CSS declared in the header-->
<div style="color:#366;">These words are in this color</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I am not using css property in hard code or inline style, for inline style i am applying class to that div like <div class="header"></div>. Also in head tag there is external css attched like <head> <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/menu.css" /></head>. But YSlow finds css in body part rather than head section.

Comment: @Nancy, thanks for clarification but I suggest you [write this into the original post](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16440152/edit) - you may get better/more answers

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this problem, and found that it was due to having an A tag before my css imports (for claiming Google Plus identity).  I moved that tag to just before the closing HEAD tag, and YSlow no longer flags the issue.